# 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am developing a website and i am finding hosting issues. I have put all my `.jsp` files in the root directory.

I am able to see the JSPs (accessing directly to them). 
But, when i try to perform the same check the WEB-INF/classes, I get the error:

`Not Found  The requested URL /AC/SearchController was not found on this server.  Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

This is my Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>AC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdvisorProfileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.AC.controller.AdvisorProfileServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdvisorProfileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AC/AdvisorProfilePage?aId=*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ForgotPasswordRedirectController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.AC.controller.ForgotPasswordURLController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ForgotPasswordRedirectController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ForgotPasswordAdvisor</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdvisorMyAccountRequest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.AC.controller.AdvisorMyAccountRequestController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdvisorMyAccountRequest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AC/requests.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ForgotPasswordRedirectControllerUser</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.AC.controller.UserForgotPasswordURLController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ForgotPasswordRedirectControllerUser</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ForgotPasswordUser</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This might also be a server config, because I created the project on Tomcat server 8, but I guess the  server which is now hosting it is Tomcat 7.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Where have you defined SearchController, i dont see it in web.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Please declare "/AC/SearchController" as url pattern in your web.xml

Comment: Actually i have also tried the url which are present in the web.xml.But Still it is showing: Not Found

The requested URL /AdvisorProfileServlet was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: please try with /ForgotPasswordAdvisor, it should work, also check your Home.jsp in in Web-content Directory

Comment: for /AC/AdvisorProfilePage?aId=* you have to match the pattern hit like /AC/AdvisorProfilePage?aId=1

Comment: Hi Prathmesh,I have made 5 folders in my WEBINF/classes folder:org.AC.controller,org.AC.DAO...etc to differentiate the classes.That is why i have given the classes path in web.xml like that.I tried /ForgotPasswordAdvisor but it is still showing 404.

Comment: And one more question i wanted to ask:If i have a form and i have given the action to a particular servlet,Then also do i have to configure it in web.xml.Because in my eclipse also i have not configured SearchController in web.xml,But the action of the search  is pointing to SearchController.This is working fine in my eclipse.

Comment: Dear Uday, your folder structure is wrong where . dot operator comes in package name java searches in the folder not for the name after dot

Comment: make folder structure like org inside that AC inside that controller etc

Comment: Hi Prathmesh,I did that but still showing :Not Found

The requested URL /SearchController was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.I am not able gauge what the problem is.I don know which part i am going wrong.But still the server is not able to find the classes,But the server is able to find the JSP's.

Comment: ok leave there might be some unknown issue,dont waste your time start with new one, please refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/index.htm

Comment: Hi Prathmesh, I just saw the error message:[Wed Nov 26 01:28:13 2014] [error] [client 122.161.93.96] File does not exist: /home/advisorcircuit/public_html/ForgotPasswordUser.It seems that the server is not looking o the servlet in WEB-INF folder.Perhaps, it is treating as a jsp.What can be done now.Also, i found .htaccess file in my WEB-INF Folder with deny from all in it.So what can be done now?